# The probability that at most 5 goblets must be selected to find 4 that are not seconds, if 10% are seconds

Tags: probability

A company that produces fine crystal knows from experience that 10% of its goblets have cosmetics flaws and must be classified as "seconds".

If goblets are examined one by one, what is the probability that at most five must be selected to find four that are not seconds?

---

Progress:   $0.9^4 + 0.4\cdot 0.9^4  = .91854$, is this a correct computation?

Comment: would you do $0.9^4 + 0.4*0.9^4$ = .91854 ?

Comment: Presumably the $0.4$ came from $4 \cdot 0.1$. If so, I think I can guess your reasons, and it all looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You approach works though, as David K says, it might be clearer to write  $0.9^4 + 4 \cdot 0.1\cdot 0.9^4  \approx 0.91854$, based on finding four unflawed or on finding three unflawed and one second is some order and then one unflawed.

Another calculation which produces the same answer is $0.9^5 + 5 \cdot 0.1\cdot 0.9^4    \approx 0.91854$, based on looking at five and finding five or four unflawed.